# Undefined symbol after removing function from source code

Tags: objective-c, c, ios, xcode, linker

I've removed a function from my Objective-C source code and now the linker complains that there's an undefined symbol referenced in CacheMgrViewController.o. I've tried cleaning the project. I've tried deleting the derived data. Nothing works. What *else* do I need to do???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have deleted the definition of the C function, but you're still actually calling it from something in or included by CacheMgrViewController.m (or CacheMgrViewController.mm).

A declaration of the definition you had deleted may still exist, or you may have not seen the warning about calling an implicit function (assuming that warning is enabled).

Resolution: Just do a project search for the function name that the linker cannot find and delete any uses of the function (that was your intent by deleting it, yes?).